# Google Drive API Member Limit

Tags: google-drive-api

I am not part of our Dev team so forgive me if im asking these questions wrong. Im trying to figure out long term solution. We are a real estate brokerage and use Drive to share all documents/paperwork/contracts. We have hit the 600 member limit that we can share the drive with. Short term we are making groups, sharing with the group and adding new members to the group. I don't want to make separate groups then add 100 members to that group long term.

I cant seem to find this answer anywhere, and im sure the answer is not quite just a yes or no. If we correctly build the share drive api into our agent portal that already uses google SSO, is the member limit still 600 or a different number limit or does anyone that can log into the portal have access to all share drive files? (ignoring the queries per day and all that stuff for now)

Thanks
Travis

Answer (score 0):

Your workaround of managing groups instead of members may reach your goal, but please be aware that there is a maximum of 100 groups per Drive. Also the sum of groups and individual members can't exceed 600. Please be aware that there is a limit of 50,000 users (counting both individual users and group members). Please take a look at [Drive sharing quotas](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7338880). For managing group membership, I strongly advise you to use the [Groups API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/groups).

Comment: Got it! thanks @jacques. So I don't actually want any groups at all, if possible.  In the link you gave for Drive Sharing Quotas. I cant seem to find it. Do you know if the Share Drive API eliminates the "Membership limits" part ?

Comment: The best approach to manage Drive sharing quotas is to organize the users into groups (one per team/project). The second best approach would be to use [Shared Drives](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7212025). In the Drive API you will encounter the same quotas, because the API is just a way to communicate to the Drive service.